# How to get Google Oauth2 id_token

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm making GAE java app

Authorization looks like

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder
            (
                    new NetHttpTransport(),
                    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                    AppConfig.clientId,
                    AppConfig.clientSecret,
                    Collections.singleton("openid email")
            )
            .setAccessType("offline").build();
```

The callback servlet is taken from here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#authorization_code_flow

Success method provided in sample looks like this:

```
 protected void onSuccess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Credential credential)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
resp.sendRedirect("/");
  }
```

from 'credential' object I can get accessToken and refreshToken. Where is id_token? How to obtain it? It's not in 'req' either.

Answer (score 1):

ID tokens are part of OpenID Connect, a protocol build on top of OAuth 2.0. If you are following that protocol, it should be available in the same response as the access token. You can see the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode).

I did not recognize the `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` class you are using; turns out it is deprecated. You may want to look at the [app engine section](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2#google_app_engine_authorization_code_flow) on the page you linked to use Google's current recommendations.

Comment: I've given a bit wrong link - it was for generic oauth2
New link is for GoogleAPI client

From there you will find that GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow class is not deprecated at all.

And my problem still stays unsolved...